# Voltages in loop not summing up to zero

Tags: circuit-analysis, rms

I have a basic series RC circuit with the following values.

Source: cos(2000pi*t)

Resistor: 1000ohm

Capacitor: 0.01uF

Upon measuring the voltages across each individual component I found that they are not adding up to zero. Is this supposed to be happening or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

These are the numbers I'm getting with the multimeter.

Source RMS: 702 mV

Resistor RMS: 358 mV

Capacitor RMS: .88mV

For the life of me I can't see why I'm getting ridiculous numbers like this.

Comment: How exactly are you measuring the voltages? Are you measuring all of the voltages simultaneously with an oscilloscope? Can you provide the measurement data?

Comment: I'm using a multimeter. I'll edit the question to include my values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected: RMS values will never add up to zero. It is the instantaneous voltage that adds up to zero. Also clear because RMS values are never negative (by definition!).

To put it slightly different: You need to take into account the relative phases of the voltages. Note, that even then, it will add up to zero only if the signals are ideally sinusoidal. That for example implies that noise needs to be negligible.

Hint: you have to measure with an oscilloscope (with a differential probe!)

EDIT: Ok, here is the behavior when you know the phase. It is the in-phase, and quadrature components that add up to zero.

The I and Q compoenents are given by

Urms_inphase = Urms * cos(phi)

and

Urms_quadrature = Urms * sin(phi)

So if you add up Urms_inphase or Urms_quadrature it will equal zero. (Provided you have sinusoidal signals!). It also shows why you have to know the phase phi of each voltage.

Comment: That would make sense. I guess I never thought about the fact that RMS values are never negative. :)

Comment: Its true what you say but how do you account for the rms voltages measured.? They don't stack up even as rms voltages.

Comment: @Andyaka still curious about that...

Comment: @Andyaka: the weight factor is cos(phi), which can be any number between -1 and 1. So it is not as easy as just subtracting or adding the rms voltages.

Comment: I would expect \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\$ to add to supplied rms voltage, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Andyaka: Well, actually, what you say is true for two noise signals, but not for sinusoids (or other non-random waveforms).